# Oracle permissions for CRUD operations

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create simple web application with privileges to create, read, update, delete from ORACLE database. In order to do that I have to create oracle user. There are so many roles and privileges. What I should enable for these operations only?

Comment: Only enable the minimum privileges necessary to allow your app to work. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

`Resources` and `create session` should be enougt:

```
GRANT CONNECT , RESOURCES TO USER_NAME.
```